# Parse - uploading data sometimes needs forever and does never finish

Tags: android, parse-platform

I just do following in a background thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) /* yes, my table is that small */
{
     ParseObject po = new ParseObject(table);
     // writing some data to the object
     // checking some defined interfaces and write data to the ParseObject...
     // here's some example code...
     if (dao instanceof IDaoNameable)
     {
        changed |= setAndCheck(po, colNameGerman, ((IDaoNameable) dao).getNameGerman());
        changed |= setAndCheck(po, colNameEnglish, ((IDaoNameable) dao).getNameEnglish());
     }
     // ...
     po.save();
}

private static boolean setAndCheck(final ParseObject po, String field, Object data)
{
    Object old = po.get(field);
    if (old != null && old.equals(data))
        return false;
    else
        po.put(field, data);
    return true;
}
```

The table does not exist yet. It will be created automatically.

I observed, that everything worked today and yesterday, but trying it at night, like now, does not work. I'm speaking about, that normally uploading needs seconds, while now it does not finish in 15min and over. The `save` is never returning... and I don't know why...

I created a parse app and just use it for myself, testing with a few data tables of size < 100 entries... Looking into analytics shows, that I'm far underneath my request limits. Are there any other limits???
Maybe a limit for table creations???

By the way, downloading table data always works... Although it seems to be a bit slower, when uploading does not work, but that may be only my feeling...

Answer (score 0):

"po.save()" in a loop is not likely not to be performant.

you want to somehow get many threads working on API calls on the parse API that dont block one another. Your current code is probably on a single thread where successive calls to 'save' are blocked waiting for previous calls to complete.

See the docs on ['bolt](http://blog.parse.com/2014/10/15/introducing-bolts-for-parse-sdks/)' ( look at the loops there ) and try to get your android SDK code doing parallel tasks wrapping the parse "saveInBackgroud()" that should be able to dispatch more than one concurrent save task.

If you really need good performance for big sets and for calling save in a loop, you might consider a full REST API like:

a multi-threaded [client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) where each connection to "parse.com" comes from a pool whose size you configure

OR

use a lib like ['retrofit'](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: Actually, I tried save in background as well and have had the same problem yesterday... I use now save because I want my data to be saved in a special order... Which seems not possible with save in background...

Comment: And for my use case, I just want to upload data on demand and wait for it... Not much data at all, actually... So I really would like to know where the problem is... I know, my approach is not the most performant one,but it should work at least, not sometimes but always...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robert Rowntree that save() in a loop is a bad practice. What you can do is create an `ArrayList<ParseObject>` and fill it up in your  loop

```
List<ParseObject> objectsToSave = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) /* yes, my table is that small */
{
     ParseObject po = new ParseObject(table);
     // writing some data to the object
     // checking some defined interfaces and write data to the ParseObject...
     // here's some example code...
     if (dao instanceof IDaoNameable)
     {
        changed |= setAndCheck(po, colNameGerman, ((IDaoNameable) dao).getNameGerman());
        changed |= setAndCheck(po, colNameEnglish, ((IDaoNameable) dao).getNameEnglish());
     }
     // ...
     objectsToSave.add(po);

}
ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(objectsToSave, saveCallback);
```

Check the [docs](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/) for more variants of this method.

Comment: As my comment to his answer says, this results in the same... I am not looking for a faster solution but a working one... Or for the season why my approach is not working... It not is slow, it just does not work always...

Comment: By the way, I want to upload my data one by one and in order... Speed is irrelevant for my current use case...

Comment: Okay. The code above should do the trick. And as an added benefit (even if you don't need it) it is more efficient

Comment: I know, I didn't say it, but I did try `saveAllInBackground` not just `saveInBackground`... I had the same problem 2 days ago... In the night... using this approach... It did not come to an end...

Comment: Actually, I will do it this way again... Still one question: Does `saveAllInBackground` use a transaction? It it fails, no data will have been saved? Or may some data be saved? I hope, first thing is true... Otherwise, this would not really be useable...